# VSCode Zen Mode specific settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, zen

I recently discovered that VSCode has Zen mode and I quickly fell in love with it.

I like to have my terminal on the side of the window when using Zen mode.
To do that I change:

```
"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "right",
```

in my user settings. But it's tedious to change this back and force all the time.

I was wondering if there is a way to have Zenmode specific settings, like it is possible to bind certain settings to themes. E.g.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[Material Theme Palenight High Contrast]": {
    "editorError.foreground": "#FF5370",
    "editorHint.foreground": "#C3E88D",
    "editorLineNumber.foreground": "#676E95",
    "editorLineNumber.activeForeground": "#80CBC4",
    "gitDecoration.deletedResourceForeground": "#FF5370",
    "gitDecoration.conflictingResourceForeground": "#FFCB6B",
    "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#82AAFF",
    "gitDecoration.untrackedResourceForeground": "#C3E88D"
  },
  "[One Dark Pro]": {
    "editor.background": "#2c313a"
  }
},
```

Comment: There isn't https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45617

Comment: You can kind of workaround it by executing multiple actions with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros

Answer (score 0):

You can always toggle the terminal window using ctrl-`
(Control - backtick).Hope that solves your problem..